# Can you use `phx.gen.html` to generate a nested resource?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

If I have resource 'Vendors' already in my Phoenix/Elixir application, and I want to add resource 'Devices' as a nested resource underneath it, how can I use `mix phx.gen.html` to generate the resource? The problem I am running into has to do with the helpers for the path functions. I.e., the device controller has a `device_path` function, when what I want is `vendor_device_path`

If the top-level generators will not work, what method can I use to get this functionality? If hand-coding is the answer, that's fine.

**Update** to clarify, here is the call I made. `mix phx.gen.html Catalog Device devices name:string vendor_id:references:vendors`, where Catalog is the context I was using.

**Second Update** This is the structure in router.ex that I would like to support.

```
resources "/vendors", VendorController do
  resources "/devices", DeviceController
end
```

I suspect that the generators would not support this out of the box, correct?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to make use of what Phoenix calls [Contexts](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/contexts.html#content). Your example might translate to something like:

```
mix phx.gen.html Vendors Devices devices field1:string --web Vendor
```

When I run this locally, `vendor_device_path` is available, and the directory structure of `lib` looks like this:

`lib
├── my_project
│   ├── application.ex
│   ├── repo.ex
│   └── vendors
│       ├── devices.ex
│       └── vendors.ex
├── my_project.ex
├── my_project_web
│   ├── channels
│   │   └── user_socket.ex
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── page_controller.ex
│   │   └── vendor
│   │       └── devices_controller.ex
│   ├── endpoint.ex
│   ├── gettext.ex
│   ├── router.ex
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── layout
│   │   │   └── app.html.eex
│   │   ├── page
│   │   │   └── index.html.eex
│   │   └── vendor
│   │       └── devices
│   │           ├── edit.html.eex
│   │           ├── form.html.eex
│   │           ├── index.html.eex
│   │           ├── new.html.eex
│   │           └── show.html.eex
│   └── views
│       ├── error_helpers.ex
│       ├── error_view.ex
│       ├── layout_view.ex
│       ├── page_view.ex
│       └── vendor
│           └── devices_view.ex
└── my_project_web.ex`

Comment: I was using contexts, btw, I added the syntax I used. Vendor is also something for which there is a controller, so I'm not sure your example is what I'm looking for, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: On the end of the command in my answer, I've got `--web Vendor` which tells Phoenix a web module namespace you want to use. That sets up the devices controller with the module name MyProject.Vendor.DeviceController, and I believe that's how the Path Helpers determine to use `vendor_device_path`. The documentation on Path Helpers explains that they are derived from the controller name used in the route definition: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html#path-helpers

Comment: Nesting the routing the way I showed above also produces `vendor_device_path`, which is what I really need as I need the `/vendor/:id/device/:id API path.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution!

Comment: I am not asking the question correctly, I think. The problem isn't that I can't get the proper Path Helper to work. It's that when you use the generator for the nested item, the generated code for the API does not provide an option (I think) for telling it that it will be nested, so that the resulting path helpers have no corresponding API call.

Comment: In that case, I think coding your solution by hand is going to be the answer. To quote the Phoenix guides: `... generators are first and foremost learning tools and a starting point for you to begin building real features. Code generation can’t solve all your problems, but it will teach you the ins and outs of Phoenix and nudge you towards the proper mind-set when designing your application.`

Comment: did you ever figure this out?